# How to convert a local datetime to UTC with moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I've found a couple of existing StackoverFlow questions on this but nothing very definite.

I have a local datetime. I want this in UTC. my local datetime does not have a 'Z' at the end or any offset information.

I first tried:

```
moment(mylocaldatetime).toISOString() #works fine because this method always returns time in UTC
```

But for consistency with other code I didn't want to use to ISOString() so I did this:

```
moment(mylocaldatetime).utc().format()
```

This seems to work fine. If the browser running this code is in UTC + 1 I get a datetime one hour less than mylocaldatetime (with an offset string if I specify that in the format). I.e. it has treated mylocaldatetime as a local time, taken account of my current time zone, and given me my local time as UTC.

However. This appears to contradict the moment.js docs which are pretty clear that:

If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use moment.utc() instead of moment(). - Notice the 'parse'.

and

Moment normally interprets input times as local times (or UTC times if moment.utc() is used).

If these doc comments were true this line:

```
moment(mylocaldatetime).utc().format()
```

should treat mylocaldatetime as if it were utc and then output this datetime in utc - no difference. No conversion. But that is not what I get.

Maybe what this line `moment(mylocaldatetime).utc().format()`  is saying is:

create a moment object in local mode with mylocaldatetime. Then put the moment object into utc mode. So now when we format for display we output as utc. IF this is the case I think the docs could be made clearer.

Comment: Your assessment is correct, and so is your code.  However, this is really not a good fit for StackOverflow.  If you feel that the docs could be clearer, then by all means - send us a pull request, or at least log it as an issue.  The entire moment.js project (including the docs) are open source.  You can find the docs repo [here](https://github.com/moment/momentjs.com).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better handled in the project's GitHub repository.

Comment: Created an issue https://github.com/moment/momentjs.com/issues/307 .